# python sorting list of dictionary by custom order

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary, lambda

I have searched that we can sort a list of dictionary by key in alphabetical order using sorted, but is it to sort it in custom order?

for example:

```
alist = [
{"id":"A","day":"sun"},
{"id":"B","day":"tue"},
{"id":"C","day":"mon"}
]
```

sort alist according to "day" in custom order i.e. `"sun", "mon", "tue"...."sat"`

```
sortedalist = [
{"id":"A","day":"sun"},
{"id":"C","day":"mon"}
{"id":"B","day":"tue"}
]
```

how can I do this? I think lambda expression is needed to be the key in sorted(), but I am not sure what should be the function

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can define a custom sort order in a dict

```
sortorder={"sun":0, "mon":1, "tue":2, "wed":3, "thu":4, "fri":5, "sat":6}
```

and then use this in the sort function:

```
my_list.sort(key=lambda x: sortorder[x["day"]])
```

This sorts the list inplace without returning a copy.

If you need a copy of the list which is sorted, then you can use

```
sorted_list=sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: sortorder[x["day"]])
```

In the original question, the variable name of the list was called `list`. Notice that it is bad practice to call a list `list` because python internals are overwritten with this.

Comment: nice. I was wondering if there'd be a way to pull `datetime` into this, since we are dealing with days of the week?

Comment: @patrick I honestly don't know. Maybe there is a way, but I don't think that the code gets any more readable, easier, more extendible or less error-prone if we use `datetime`. But if you find a clever way, please edit my answer or write a new one - the academic interest definitely exists :)

Comment: Thanks! The key is not exactly the same in my problem, I just want to generalize the problem and make it easy to understand. I have modified the variable to not confuse the others!

Comment: Is it possible to do this if I have a sort_order which is a <list> ?